# urllib2 and BeautifulSoup - loop through urls and return whether html contains "<form" tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am a Python novice and have no experience with BeautifulSoup and urllib

I've tried to frankenstein my own code from other questions to no avail, so I will try to detail what I’m trying to achieve from the pseudocode and description below:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for eachurl in "urllist.txt":
    urllib read first (or 2nd or 3rd) url in list
    find.all("<form")
    if number of "<form" > 0:
        result = True
    if number of "<form" == 0:
        result = False

write result to csv/excel/html

table col 1 = url in urllist
table col 2 = result
```

So basically, I have a txt file with a list of URLs in; I would like urllib to open each URL one by one and see whether or not the html contains a form tag. (Writing to a new file) the URL string in the left column and a `y` or `n` in the right, depending on whether finding all form tag returned a result greater than 0, and then of course stop once the URLs have been exhausted in the txt file.

Comment: So what is the exact problem? Does the first part of your code work? SO is not a coding service so please specify your problem.

Comment: You need to read up on opening and reading files, fetching resources with urllib, using BS, and writing csv files. There is plenty of documentation and tutorials around for each of these. I suggest that you find them and read them with a view to _understanding_ how they work. SO is about helping to solve specific problems, not writing code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        res = requests.get(line.strip()).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
        with open('result.txt', 'a') as result_file:
            if soup.find_all('form'):
                result_file.write('{} y\n'.format(line.strip()))
            else:
                result_file.write('{} n\n'.format(line.strip()))
```

data.txt

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263219/urllib2-and-beautifulsoup-loop-through-urls-and-return-whether-html-contains
http://blank.org/
```

result.txt

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263219/urllib2-and-beautifulsoup-loop-through-urls-and-return-whether-html-contains y
http://blank.org/ n
```